# how to emulate parameters passed by reference

Tags: r, reference, parameter-passing

Is there a way?
***NB***: the question is not whether it is right, good or sensible to do such a thing.
The question is if there is a way, so if your answer would be 
"why would you want to do that?" "R uses functions what you want was once called procedure and good R usage/style does not ...", "could you explain better... provide some code" do NOT answer.

I did a quick try, that <s>did not work</s> eventually worked, using environments, more or less:

```
function(mydf) {
  varName <- deparse(substitute(mydf))
  ...
  assign(varName,mydf,envir=parent.frame(n = 1))
}
```

Comment: This is a "how to" question for usage of R language that is at least medium level or, more likely, advanced. The reputation of the author of the chosen answer should make it clear, if, strangely, it isn't.

Comment: If this is off topic then it's time to delete my account from this site

Comment: Why has my account not yet been deleted? Please delete it asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Wrap the function body in `eval.parent(substitute({...}))` like this:

```
f <- function(x) eval.parent(substitute({
  x <- x + 1
}))

mydf <- data.frame(z = 1)
f(mydf)
mydf
##   z
## 1 2
```

Also see the `defmacro` function in gtools and the wrapr package.

**2)** An alternative might be to use a replacement function:

```
"incr<-" <- function(x, value) {
      x + value
}

mydf <- data.frame(z = 1)
incr(mydf) <- 1
mydf
##   z
## 1 2
```

**3)** or just overwrite the input:

```
f2 <- function(x) x + 1
mydf <- data.frame(z = 1)
mydf <- f2(mydf)
mydf
##   z
## 1 2
```

If the problem is that there are multiple outputs then use `list` in the gsubfn package.  This is used on the left hand side of an assignment with square brackets as shown.  See `help(list, gsubfn)`

```
library(gsubfn)
f3 <- function(x, y) list(x + 1, y + 2)
mydf <- mydf2 <- data.frame(z = 1)
list[mydf, mydf2] <- f3(mydf, mydf2)
mydf
##   z
## 1 2
mydf2
##   z
## 1 3
```

Comment: @user516548 this question has been put on hold as inappropriate (seeking debug help) to me it seems exactly the type of question  stackoverflow was born for.

Answer (score 1):

At least for my specific/limited needs I found a solution

```
myVar = 11

myF <- function(x) {
  varName <- deparse(substitute(x))
  # print(paste("var name is", varName))
  x = 99
  assign(varName,x,envir=parent.frame(n = 1))
  NA # sorry this is not a function
  # in real life sometimes you also need procedures
}

myF(myVar)
print(myVar)
# [1] 99
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to emulate call-by-reference. However, several tricks can be used from case to case:

globals: It is, of course, possible to have a global variable instead of the parameter. This can be written from within a function using <<- instead of = or <-. In this way, many cases of needing call-by-reference vanish.

However, this is not compatible with parallelization and also not compatible with recursion.

When you need recursion, you can do very much the same and have a global stack. Before the recursive call, you have to append to this stack and as the first line of your function, you can get the index (similar to a stack pointer in CPUs) in order to write to the global stack.

Both approaches are not encouraged and should be used as a last resort or for education. If you really can't avoid call-by-reference, go to C++ with Rcpp and write a C++-function that does your heavy loading. If needed, it can actually call R functions. Look at some Rcpp tutorials, most of them cover this case...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was familiar with <<- but, if I remember well (back to R after some time, never had the time to enojoy learning it properly)  <<- forced me to hardcode the variable name. I have taken 20 mins time and made my originary code work. The fact that both approaches should not work with recursion might not be a problem, at least for my personal experience, when I used recursion it was to do functional-style things, and there I neved needed pass by reference, think that that might be general.

Comment: Interesting concern with the variable name being hard-coded. Overlooked that limitation...

Comment: It is necessary to make the function (logically a procedure) usable with different variables, a requirement for my use case (didn't quote it not to make question to complex)