# How to create and initialize a non existing variable to a default value in R?

Tags: r, types, casting, initialization, undefined

This question **originates from curiosity**, I have nothing to deliver based on this.

Mimicking pass-by-reference ([question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609171/r-how-to-emulate-parameters-passed-by-reference)) I noticed that both approaches described in the answers obviously fail when the variable does not exist and one tries to use/reference them.

Regardless of its actual usefulness, I would be curious to know if there is a way to initialize the parameter x in the code below, and hence the "actual" parameter myVar, to a default value, with the help of the desired type passed as a string, xtype (passing the type, and in such basic form is not a requirement, it is simply the first thing that came to my mind of non-advanced R programmer).

The question whose solution generated this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609171/r-how-to-emulate-parameters-passed-by-reference),  shows better code in the chosen answer, here using my code as I understand it better

```
myF <- function(x, xtype) {
  varName <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if (!exists(varName)) {
    # here should initialize x to a default value
    # of the type passed in xtype 
    # to avoid that x <- x ... fails
    # this may not have any practical usefulness, just curious
  }
  x <- x+1
  assign(varName,x,envir=parent.frame(n = 1))
  NA # sorry this is not a function
  # in real life sometimes you also need procedures
}
if (exists(deparse(substitute(myVar)))) {
  rm(myVar)
}
myF(myVar, "numeric")
print(myVar)
Error in myF(myVar, "numeric") : object 'myVar' not found
# as expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for (even though it's a terrible idea to write a function like this in R).

```
myF <- function(x, xtype) {
  varName <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if (!exists(varName)) {
    x <- vector(xtype, 1)
  } else {
    x <- get(varName)
  }
  x <- x+1
  assign(varName,x,envir=parent.frame(n = 1))
}
```

Comment: It was a curiosity. Thanks for your useful direct and clear answer.